# Mean distance vs. mean of disances in igraph

Tags: r, distance, igraph

I am trying to calculate the average path length for my network and I face the following issue. I the past I have beed using the `average.path.length` from the `igraph` package. This time I decided to take a different route: I wanted to use the `distances` function (also from package `igraph`) and then find mean of all distances. It was my understanding that the `distances` function simply calculates pairwise shortest paths between vertices of a graph and thus taking `mean(distances(graph))` should return average path length. However, when I tried to use this approach I noticed that I am getting different values that the directs application of `average.path.length` and `mean_distance` was giving. Initially I thought that the problem is caused by some isolate nodes but when I checked it on a fully connected toy graph I had the same problem.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
  toy.graph <- graph.formula(1-2,1-3,1-5,2-5,3-5,3-6,4-6)
  mean_distance(toy.graph)
  [1] 1.866667
  average.path.length(toy.graph)
  [1] 1.866667
  mean(distances(toy.graph))
  [1] 1.555556
```

I understand that different algorithms are used for `mean_distance` and `distances` but should the difference be so big on such a small and simple model? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are getting a different answer because you are averaging the entire distance matrix instead of the lower|upper triangle of `distance(toy.graph)` this includes a 0's on the diagonal which lower the distance

```
library(igraph)
toy.graph <- graph.formula(1-2,1-3,1-5,2-5,3-5,3-6,4-6)
plot(toy.graph)
mean_distance(toy.graph)
#[1] 1.866667

average.path.length(toy.graph)
#[1] 1.866667

mean(distances(toy.graph))
#[1] 1.555556

mean(distances(toy.graph)[lower.tri(distances(toy.graph))])
#[1] 1.866667
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I can see that the diagonal will lower the average. Should I use both lower and upper triangle when my network is directed? In such case the matrix will not be symmetric (although it will still have 0 on the diagonal).

Comment: If you want to use this method for directed graphs then you need to calculate the "in" and "out" distance for the graph, remove the "Inf" and the diagonal before averaging. That's works for a simple directed graph, not sure how generalizable this would be though